# JSLint "Unsafe character"

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, jslint

I was happily using Douglas Crockford's JSLint on Mac OS X and my code passes, but after I got a Ubuntu Hardy Slicehost server and uploaded my code there, the JSLint no longer passes when I try to run it on the server. It fails on my localized files that contain umlauts.

I get errors like:

```
Lint at line 1206 character 25: Unsafe character.
"PREVIOUS" : "zur??ck",

Lint at line 1207 character 26: Unsafe character.
"NEXTPAGE" : "vorw??rts",
```

The file hasn't changed, I checked the MD5 hash and they are same on both. This is how I run JSLint from my deployment script:

```
def lint_ok(fn):
    return os.system("java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main jslint/jslint.js %s" % fn) == 0
```

Any ideas? What could be different? I checked the environment (env / set) and the only reference to character sets / encodings was "LC_CTYPE=UTF-8". I tried setting it to be the same but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: This is most likely a file encoding problem that happened when you switched platforms. Where are you running the JSLint from, the Mac or Linux?

Comment: Also, can you find out what encoding your files are in? Many IDEs can auto-detect it. Try to re-save as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, respectively, depending on what you need.

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8 (which is what I want). I was running on Mac, then moved it to Linux. JSLint ran fine on Mac but apparently I have my environment set wrong somehow on Linux since I get errors there.

Comment: sorry, I overread the md5 part and that you already checked that they are identical. Strange - it shouldn't really depend on the environment how JSLint parses a file, should it? Does JSLint have any configuration options for the encoding of incoming data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question this may be related to "unsafe characters". See [JsLint documentation](http://www.jslint.com/help.html)

> There are characters that are handled
>   inconsistently in browsers, and so
>   must be escaped when placed in
>   strings.

I'm running into a similar problem although it appears the BOM mark at the start of the file prevents JsLint going further.

There is a [bugfix here](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/issues/detail?id=37) for some java port of JsLint that addresses this issue.